# android, layout contents all squeezed together

Tags: android, android-layout

I made an activity for input basic experiment information. The layout is made based on a SamsungGalaxy note pro. In order to make the text larger, I put all text size to be 30dp. As a result, all context are squeezed together in a smaller screen. As shown on pictures. 
[image]

[image]

So is there a way to key text size relatively large on the galaxy note, but when it is on a smaller device the layout becomes longer than the screen and user simply scroll down to access other editText instead of squeezing everything to one screen page? Here is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.myname.appname.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:id="@+id/titleLayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcomeTexView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/welcome"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:id="@+id/informationLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/infolayout1"
                android:layout_weight="0.1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="IP: "
                    android:id="@+id/ipViewHeader"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ip_address"
                    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                    android:digits="0123456789."
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:onClick="enterIP"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/infolayout2"
                android:layout_weight="0.1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/studyprefix"
                    android:id="@+id/prefixViewHeader"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/prefixText"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="rating-emo9"
                    android:onClick="enterPrefix"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/infolayout3"
                android:layout_weight="0.1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/userid"
                    android:id="@+id/idViewHeader"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/idText"
                    android:hint="3001"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:onClick="enterUserid"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/infolayout4"
                android:layout_weight="0.1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/username"
                    android:id="@+id/usernameViewHeader"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/uernameText"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/myname"
                    android:onClick="enterMyname"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/infolayout5"
                android:layout_weight="0.1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/soundmodel"
                    android:id="@+id/modelViewHeader"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/modelRadioGroup"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">


                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/abs"
                        android:id="@+id/abstractRB"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:onClick="onModelChoice" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/vocal"
                        android:id="@+id/vocalRB"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:onClick="onModelChoice" />

                </RadioGroup>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/infolayout6"
                android:layout_weight="0.1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/run"
                        android:id="@+id/runViewHeader"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/runText"
                        android:hint="0"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:onClick="enterRun" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/nrstim"
                        android:id="@+id/runView"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/nrstimText"
                        android:hint="0"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:onClick="enterNrstim" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:id="@+id/startLayout">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/startTest"
                android:id="@+id/StartTest"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:onClick="onStartButton" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a ScrollView with the fillViewport property for the ScrollView set to fill the screen?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. By the way, can you advice on how to make text size relative to the screen? If I dont defined textsize = 30dp. It looks fine on Nexus but way too small on Galaxy note.

Comment: Use the **android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"** properties.. it has for Medium and Large options too. this can scale much better than actual digits